# Using v-if in a template inside a computed property doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, templates, computed-properties

I have a computed property that has an html template (yes unfortunately I have to use it this way) inside it. I want to have a v-if attribute inside the template but it returns an error which I believe is because the variable is being read as a string. How can I fix that?

This is my computed property:

```
         myProperty(row){
            return `<div class="cell__customer-contact">
                      <div>${row.customerFirstName +
                        " " +
                        row.customerLastName}</div>
                      <div v-if="${row.customerEmail}"> 
                        <a href="mailto:${row.customerEmail}">
                          ${row.customerEmail}
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>`
         }
```

The error I get is:

```
invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in

    user@gmail.com

  Raw expression: v-if="user@gmail.com"
```

Comment: How do you render `myProperty`?

Comment: I guess you can wrap the email in quotes inside the v-if, but not 100% sure.